# inheriting from another css class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a problem here that i can't seem to figure out, till now my css has been a little slapdash and it was always a case of hack away till it looks right but i've decided to learn it properly and i'm trying to categorize things as much as i can.

So i have a layout that has an unordered list, this list has three li tags, within each of these li tags are two div each.

Now i have a class for each of these containers, they can be called container_1 container_2 and so on.

Now they have some unique attributes to each of them but they al also follow a set style for example, the divs in each li are side by side so its sets of two divs also they are all going to have round corners.

So i thought i could make a class class rounded_corners plus float_left and float_right so instead of re typing the code to round the corns or float something i could just reference thing class like this:

```
.container_1 .rounded_corners .float_left
{

}
 .container_2 .rounded_corners .float_right
{

}
```

But when i use this i loose my styling so i used a comma and this allowed the sty;ing for the div to come back but the corners and floats didn't work.

So where am i going wrong with this?

This is my code, i have taken the code out that breaks the layout, but if you remove the comments you can see what happens.

http://jsfiddle.net/ragebunnykickass/g3Zaz/

The naming is a little different but you'll know what is meant.

Thanks.

Comment: Just for future reference: Class names based on *how things look* are not recommended. Class names based on *what things represent* are much better.

Comment: @RyanKinal Thanks for the tip buddy, these names are just for test purposes at the moment, usually i am very strict with naming (It's the one thing i am strict with haha)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

CSS classes cannot inherit so what you have to do is split them to be as much atomic as possible. For example if you have a rounded-corners class and it *may* be applicable to containers:

```
.rounded-corners
{
   /* Your CSS to define rounded corners */
}
```

Note that you define ONLY the properties for rounded corners. Now let's say you have a class to style containers (for example with a proper padding):

```
.container
{
    /* Your CSS to define a nice container */
}
```

How to combine them together? This won't be done in CSS but in HTML, in this example this `<div>` inherits from both `container` and `rounded-corners`:

```
<div class="container rounded-corners">
</div>
```

Now suppose you need rounded corners for a non container object:

```
<div class="rounded-corners">
</div>
```

This is how CSS works. Do not compare them (because of name) with classes of object oriented languages. Each class define a set of attributes that will be applied to all elements that belong to that class. Final element style is the *composition* of the attributes inherited from each class that element belongs to.

**NOTE**: to summarize: answer is *yes, you may have to repeat some code*. You'll have trouble to manage your code (both HTML and CSS) if you use classes as short names for a style: you'll see you missed the point to separate content from style (because in HTML you'll define, using a class like `rounded-corners`, an *explicit* appearance). Imagine: next month you have to change your web-site style and fashion requirements impose you have square corners. You have to change your HTML code (unless you accept to have a `rounded-corners` class to apply a squared border). Much better if you simply say `container` and you let your CSS to define (and know) how a `container` should be rendered.

It may be applicable to you or not (it depends on your preferences, taste and development environment) but you may take a look to [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). It's implemented as a JavaScript that will parse your CSSs. Of course you won't write a pure valid CSS but you'll gain many new features. In your case you may find [mixins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) are what you need:

```
.rounded-corners
{
    /* Your CSS here */
}

.float-left
{
    /* Your CSS here */
}

.container
{
    .rounder-corners
    .float-left
}
```

Comment: I see, i think i am struggling to change my way of thinking of classes, i am used to using OO languages. As far as the last note, are you saying that using a class with a name such as rounded_corners is bad because it doesn't explain what the class is is i end up just using class="rounded_corners" ?

Comment: Maybe something like market_card_boder_style would explain things a lot more.

Comment: @ragebunny no, it's not because of the meaning. Try to answer: if, for example, cellpadding attribute is considered evil (because you mix content with style in HTML) then why rounded-corners should be better? You write in HTML something about appearance too. "container" is good (you say it's a container, you don't ask how it should be rendered). I added a small example about LESS, take a look to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the that answer, it has really help me out! I will have a look at LESS. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a CSS code like:

```
.container_1 {

}
.rounded_corners {

}
.float_left {

}
```

and then set a class to HTML element in this way:

```
<div class="container_1 rounded_corners float_left">...</div>
```

So the DIV element will inherit every style of every class!
Obviously, DIV it's just an example, you could use every tag!

Answer (score 0):

If i get it well, you want a set of classes to apply to each div?

I'd break it up like that :

css

```
.rounded_corners {}
.float_left {}
.float_right {}
.container {}
```

and in the html

```
<li id="container_1" class="container float_left rounded_corners">...</li>
<li id="container_2" class="container float_right rounded_corners">...</li>
```

etc...

Comment: So there i no way of me using the rounded_corner class with my container class in the css sheet?

Comment: There is no tidier way of doing this, because putting multiple classes into the class attribute in the html seem so messy to be and you are always told to make things as clear and clean as possible.

Comment: well you could put the 'rounded_corners' properties in the 'container' class, if all your containers have this property